# iCare recovered files from a formatted partition but they all have an incorrect extension

Tags: data-recovery, hard-drive-recovery, file-recovery

I have a HDD partition that was formatted and I needed to recover the files.
After formatting, the partition was not used anymore.
I used iCare to recover the files and after 4 hours of scan it found exactly 500gb of files.
Originally, these files were images, movies and docs.
All of the recovered filenames have the .swf extension.
I don't understand why all of the recovered files have this extension instead of the correct extension. How do I find the original extension for each of the files so that they can be returned to how they were originally.

Comment: At least search .swf

Comment: I know what swf is. But why all files have that extension. There was no swf files before.

Comment: That is not clear from your question. I suggest you edit your question and actually ask what you want to know :)

Comment: In scan result there are no my files. Size of result is fine but all files looks like 5432.swf, 754368.swf etc. My question is what to do with theese files do I need to convert them somehow to get deleted files or that is some error?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows then use [Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva/download)